# How to emulate mouse click using wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

Is there any function in wxWidgets framework, say, click(), whose function is to emulate a left-click mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no function like this. If you really need to do it, e.g. because you want to perform some action in another application you need to write platform-specific code yourself (e.g. use SendInput() under Windows).

If you want to use this to execute some code in your own application though, there is a much better solution: instead of doing unsupported, fragile and ugly

```
void MyClass::OnLeftUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
   ... do something with click at event.GetPosition() ...
}

void MyOtherFunction()
{
  wxMouseEvent event(...);
  ... initialization not shown because there is no right way to do it anyhow ...
  myObject->ProcessEvent(event);
}
```

just refactor your code to do it like this instead:

```
void MyClass::OnLeftUp(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
   HandleClick(event.GetPosition());
}

void MyClass::HandleClick(const wxPoint& pos)
{
   ... do something with click at pos  ...
}

void MyOtherFunction()
{
  myObject->HandleClick(position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just talking about emulating a click on another button in your wxWidgets app, I've tried this before:

Create a fake wxEvent of the right type, tell the event what object to care
   about using SetEventObject(), and tell a parent wxWindow in the hierarchy to
   ProcessEvent(myNewEvent). You might want to use wxGetTopLevelParent() to get the topmost frame/dialog

If you are talking about emulating a click in another, non-wxWidgets process, it's possible you could use the OS's accessibility APIs to do this. wxAccessibility should be able to help with this on Windows -- for other OSes, last I heard (granted, a few years ago), you'll have to use the native OS functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wxControl::Command() method. According to Documentation:

> Simulates the effect of the user issuing a command to the item.

[Documentation page](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_control.html#a8cd7ac81debaf506d6d146528c3d9a82)

[List of events to use with wxCommandEvent constructor](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__funcmacro__events.html#gad98d3ca1e118c5aaca40e24935448040)

You can simulate a click on a button like this:

```
$this->MyButton->Command(new wxCommandEvent(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED));
```

There is also the [wxUIActionSimulator](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_u_i_action_simulator.html) class that you can use to simulate UI actions.